# diff between local and Hadoop file

Tags: linux, shell, hadoop, diff, bin

I am trying the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read LINE
do
diff source_$LINE <(hadoop fs -cat /user/hadoop-path/$LINE/output) > diff_$LINE
done < FILE
```

It works fine from cmd Line but from shell it gives the error:
Syntax error near unexpected token `('

Any help please?

Comment: try changing the shebang line to either `!#/bin/bash` or `!#/bin/ksh`. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Process substitution is not available in the POSIX shell (`#!/bin/sh`). Your interactive shell is apparently `bash`, while your script is not. Either change the shebang to `#!/bin/bash`, or use a here document in the script:

```
diff source_$LINE - <<EOF > diff_$LINE
$(hadoop fs -cat /usr/hadoop-path/$LINE/output)
EOF
```